# Typescript optimal solution to two for Each Loop

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have just written a simple forEach loop two time and I was trying to look for a more optimal way to write this. I thought maybe I can filter directly and then return the result but again I will then have to run another loop for updating another object. So is there any optimal way to do this?

```
let shift = (
    list: list[],
    fileId: string,
    folderId: string
): list[] => {
    if (list.length > 0) {
        let updatedList = list;
        let fileToReplace: any = {};
        let isAFile: number = 0;
        let isAFolder: number = 0;

        updatedList.forEach((item: list) => {
            item.files.forEach((fileItem: {id: string, name: string}, index: number) => {
                if (fileItem.id === fileId) {
                    fileToReplace = fileItem
                    item.files.splice(index, 1);
                    isAFile = isAFile + 1;
                }
            });
        });
        updatedList.forEach((item: list) => {
            if (item.id === folderId) {
                item.files.push(fileToReplace);
                isAFolder = isAFolder + 1;
            }
        });
        if (isAFile === 0) {
            throw new Error('You cannot move a folder');
        }
        if (isAFolder === 0) {
            throw new Error('You cannot specify a file as the destination');
        }
        return updatedList;
    }
    else {
        throw new Error('This resource cannot be empty');
    }

};
```

Comment: What is *n* when you say it has O(n²) complexity? Also, your code does not work well when there are multiple matches.

Comment: Ther O(n^2) was for the first forEach loop and nested inside it another forEach loop. All in all I wanted to find an optimal way to do this task. So that I won't have to write any extra loop again for updating array.

Comment: Yes, but the two loops loop over different things. If the total number of files is *n*, split over *m* folders, then the complexity is O(m+n). As you need to potentially check each file, there is no way to make it more efficient in terms of complexity, although you could write it a bit nicer.

Comment: Okay thank you but can you give any nicer shape to it then? I was thinking of making arraw functions and calling them in forEach. Do you've any nicer way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity cannot be improved as potentially all files need to be compared with the given identifier. But if you expect only one match (as your code is suggesting), then you could exit the loop when the match is found. You can also benefit from the `.find` and `.findIndex` methods.

I would also avoid naming a variable `list`, when `list` is also a name of a type.

For instance, here is some (untested) rewrite of your code:

```
let shift = (
    resource: list[],
    fileId: string,
    folderId: string
): list[] => {
    if (resource.length === 0) {
        throw new Error('This resource cannot be empty');
    }
    let target: list | null = resource.find(({id}: {id: string}) => id === folderId);
    if (target === null) {
        throw new Error('The destination is not a folder in this resource');
    }
    for (let item: list of resource) {
        let index: number = item.files.findIndex(({id}: {id: string}) => id === fileId);
        if (index < 0) continue;
        target.files.push(item.files.splice(index, 1)[0]);
        return resource;
    }
    throw new Error('The item to move is not a file in this resource');
};
```